# Ajax GET throwing 404 errors in Chrome Console

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, get, http-status-code-404

This is not effecting my page or output but I was wondering if someone can explain why this is happening:

Here is my Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$archive = "/videoarchive/";

$.ajax({
  url: "http://mysite.com/videoarchive/",
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
    $div = $('.archive', $(html));
    $img = $div.first().find('img').attr('src');
    $link = $div.first().find('a').attr('href');
    alert($img);
    $('#featureVideo').append('<img src="http://mysite.com/videoarchive/'+$img+'" alt="image" />');
    $('#playVideo').append('<a class="extLink" href="http://mysite.com/videoarchive/'+$link+'" target="_blank" title="fancybox link"><img src="images/playButton.png" alt="image" /></a>');
    $('#archiveLinks').append('');

});

});
```

Everything works fine but when I inspect element and look in the console all the images from the incoming HTML all add the path to my website. Here is an example:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) >>>  http://mysite.com/webapps/r2ewg/images/diversity_scanline.jpg

I am just curious if there is a way to get rid of these or if I am stuck with them. OR if I am doing something wrong...

Works fine in Chrome and IE8...
The output will only be seen in IE8 on an Intranet site...

Let me know if I can provide more details?

Comment: is there any possbility that some other piece of code is causing this error?

Comment: The video archive page I am pulling the data from links to the images like this src="images/thisimage.jpg" and when ajax gets the code from the page, then puts it into HTML format it adds the http:mysite.com/yadda yadda in front of it I tried doing .each() and prepend() the correct path but it didn't work. Is there a particular piece of code I can provide for you?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, should you be wrapping html twice? Instead do:

```
$div = $('.archive', html);
```

Comment: Could your provide the benefits to doing it this way? I made the change and it made no difference in the output. Everything still works fine and I am still getting the errors. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

What might be happening is that when you get a response back from the ajax call, you're getting a bunch of HTML and that URL (http://mysite.com/webapps/r2ewg/images/diversity_scanline.jpg) is part of it.

If that chunk of HTML is appended to your DOM, the browser will attempt to grab the image.  The browser is probably trying to load the image and getting a 404.  It might not even have anything to do with your jQuery at all.

Comment: This is what it looks like on the target page:  <img src="images/gen_BehaviorMatters032013.jpg" alt="EDO Message: Behavior Matters " border="0"> Then when it throws the error it says the path is:  http://mysite.com/webapps/r2ewg/images/gen_BehaviorMatters032013.jpg

Comment: I can't tell if you're sanitizing the URL for the sake of this post, or if those are the actual URLs that are being generated.  From your code, you're pulling the URL from a src attribute with the path "images/gen_BehaviorMatters032013.jpg", then adding it to the string 'http://r2.nrc.gov/videoarchive/'+$img+' and appending a new image node to your page.  The browser is then going to make a call to http://r2.nrc.gov/videoarchive/images/gen_BehaviorMatters032013.jpg. So, if the browser can't hit that URL to pull the image, the console will report a 404 and the image should not appear.

Comment: it doesn't give that url in the error though it gives the path to where the files are on the server